# Center SVG made with Inkscape in PDF document exported by Lyx

Tags: lyx, pdf, svg

I have a SVG made with Inkscape (Windows) imported into my Lyx document,

https://www.lyx.org/

but the exported PDF shows the image beyond the page boundary

PDF here

https://github.com/pedro-vicente/transport/blob/master/transport.pdf

and .lyx, .tex and .svg sources in the same repository

```
\begin_layout Standard
\align center
\begin_inset Graphics
    filename figure_1.svg

\end_inset


\end_layout
```

EDIT:

@scottkosty, thanks, I exported the section of the image, with text above and below to the following LaTex

```
%% LyX 2.3.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% A simple dot to overcome graphicx limitations
\newcommand{\lyxdot}{.}


\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
In the Finite Volume Method, values for the above diferential equations
are calculated at discrete places on a grid of volumes, shown in Figure
1,
\begin{center}
\includepdf{figure_1}
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Figure 1}: Temperature at center of cell, and on left and
right cell borders.
\par\end{center}

\noindent 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you try converting your .svg to a .pdf (e.g., in Inkscape you can export) and instead include the PDF in your document? Likely LyX is doing that conversion behind-the-scenes, so this way we will know whether it is the behind-the-scenes conversion that's causing problems or the LaTeX placement.

Comment: I converted the .svg to .pdf, and then in Lyx Insert->File->Extern Material with PDF Pages template. The image fits on the page now, but it has huge spaces before and after
\begin_layout Standard
\align center
\begin_inset External
 template PDFPages
 filename figure_1.pdf

\end_inset

Comment: I suggest you make a LaTeX minimal example. To do that, in LyX go to File > Export > LaTeX (pdflatex). The reason for that is that most people on this site do not use LyX, but they can still comment on a possible solution if you post the .tex. Please post a complete minimal example, not just the part about the graphics. It's great that you link to the actual PDF file. That will be helpful! If you don't get a response here, consider writing to the lyx-users email list.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed just by changing the width and height of the .svg in Inkscape, and then importing in .lyx. Lyx even automatically displays the change if the .svg file changed.

Comment: Is this an answer to your problem? If this is not the case, please edit the question directly.